OpenAPI Auth Flow with csrf token
I'm writing an OpenAPI spec for an external API. The API requires two steps for authentication. The user first needs to GET / to obtain a session cookie and a CSRF token. Then, the user logs into via POST /login with the session cookie and logs into the session.
Is there something more elegant that I can do with OpenAPI than the following?
components:
  securitySchemes:
    sessionCookie:
      type: apiKey
      in: cookie
      name: session

  parameters:
    CSRFTokenHeader:
      name: X-CSRF-TOKEN
      in: header
      required: false
      schema:
        type: string

  schemas:
    LoginRequest:
      type: object
      required:
        - username
        - password
        - _csrf
      properties:
        username:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string
        _csrf:
          type: string
          description: CSRF token obtained from initial request

paths:
  /:
    get:
      tags:
        - session
      operationId: getInitialSession

  /login:
    post:
      tags:
        - session
      operationId: loginUser
      security:
        - sessionCookie: []
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/LoginRequest'


I'm using @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli to generate a Python client and the resulting code looks as follows.
session_api = my_api.SessionApi(api_client=client)
init_result = session_api.get_initial_session_with_http_info()
assert init_result.headers
client.cookie = init_result.headers["Set-Cookie"]
csrf_token = init_result.headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"]
session_api.login_user_with_http_info(
    username=os.environ.get("MY_API_USERNAME"),
    password=os.environ["MY_API_PASSWORD"],
    csrf=csrf_token,
)

